# Set Background png image from external storage

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to set background to some buttons that are created automatically. I have downloaded some pictures here `ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
        directory = cw.getDir("archivos", MainActivity.MODE_PRIVATE);`

I want to set the backgroud something like this

```
Button botonCanal = new Button(this);
            botonCanal.setLayoutParams(lp);
            String dive = String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
            int id = MainActivity.this.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", directory+"");
            botonCanal.setBackgroundResource(id);
            botonCanal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
```

How can I set an image from `/data/user/0/com.example.fcv.tvprueba/app_archivos` that is where the images are.

Comment: Use `directory` and the filename to create a `File` object that you can use with `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` to get a `Bitmap`. Then create a `BitmapDrawable` from that `Bitmap` to use with `botonCanal.setBackground()`. Alternatively, use an image handling library, like Glide or Picasso, to do that for you, especially if you need to resize the images, and/or load a bunch of them.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I create a `BitmapDrawable` from the `Bitmap`. Now, I have this `File fondoBoton = readFileFromInternalStorage(MainActivity.this, "archivos", fondo);
            Bitmap bitmapFondo = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fondoBoton + "");`

Comment: `BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapFondo);`